# Pusher : Couldn't retrieve authentication info

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

Using Laravel echo, pusher and vuejs.

Whenever I try to join a private channel(the channel of the own user) y get this error

```
"Pusher : Couldn't retrieve authentication info. 419Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users"
```

Here is the moment I join a the channel:

```
Echo.private('App.User.' + response.data.currentUser)
.listen('Event',(e)=>{});
```

`response.data.currentUser` does contain correctly the id of the user.

Here is the channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    if (Auth::user()->id == (int) $id) {
        return ['STATUS' => 'OK'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I solve this

Comment: Did you authenticate to the channel?

Comment: Yes. I did authenticate

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @allaghi If I do find a solution I'll post it. It is really annoying and I can't do anything if I don't get rid of that error.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosF me as well if I find the solution I am gonna post it

Comment: @CarlosF, check  my solution , it works with me,

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding this

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({

    "authEndpoint": "/your-project-name/broadcasting/auth",
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
   key: '####################',
   cluster : "mt1",
   encrypted: true

});
```

Comment: where did you add it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it turned out to be that my server was missing the `PHP curl extension.`

I was getting this error first:

[image]

> Call to undefined method Pusher\Pusher::socket_auth()

Then I tried installing:

```
composer require pusher/pusher-http-laravel
```

Which gave the *PHP extension curl is missing from your system* error.

[image]

After installing it *php-curl* with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

It fixed everything and is now working.